# Python large .tsv file to .csv file

Tags: python, csv

In fact, the codes below can successfully convert the `.tsv` file into `.csv` file, however, when the file is large (like more than 1GB), it has a `MemoryError` in the `read` function.

```
import re
tsv = open('tsv.tsv', 'r')
fileContent =  tsv.read()
fileContent = re.sub("\t", ",", fileContent) # convert from tab to comma
csv_file = open("csv.csv", "w")
csv_file.write(fileContent)
csv_file.close()
```

I know that by reading a large file, I can use the codes below:

```
with open("data.txt") as myfile:
    for line in myfile:
```

But I do not know how to combine these two codes into one and work properly to convert a large size .tsv file into .csv file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just sticking your two snippets directly together:

```
with open("data.txt", 'r') as myfile:
  with open("csv.csv", 'w') as csv_file:
    for line in myfile:
      fileContent = re.sub("\t", ",", line)
      csv_file.write(fileContent)
```

Comment: I added a line because I had commas that were breaking my output CSV:
`for line in myfile:
    line = line.replace(",", '.')
        fileContent = re.sub("\t", ",", line)`

Answer (score 2):

For the large files use pandas, not pure Python:

```
import pandas as pd
dfs = pd.read_csv('file.tsv', sep='\t', chunksize=50)
for df in dfs:
    df.to_csv('file.csv', sep=',', mode='a')
```

Comment: @androidnewbie I have edited my answer, also please read pandas documentation http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20.2/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html